# How to get the correct output of this code from Tensorflow?

Tags: python, tensorflow

I am taking a beginner Stanford course on the Stanford page. I was doing one of the exercises but got the wrong output. The code is this:

```html
import os
os.environ['TF_CPP_MIN_LOG_LEVEL']='2'
import tensorflow as tf


my_var = tf.compat.v1.Variable(2, name='my_var')
my_var_times_2 = tf.compat.v1.Variable(2 * my_var)

init_op = tf.compat.v1.global_variables_initializer()

with tf.compat.v1.Session() as sess:
    sess.run(init_op)
    print(sess.run(my_var_times_2))
    print(sess.run(my_var_times_2))
    print(sess.run(my_var_times_2))
```

The output was this:

**WARNING:tensorflow:From C:\Users\visha\anaconda3\lib\site-packages\tensorflow\python\ops\variables.py:2618: Variable.initialized_value (from tensorflow.python.ops.variables) is deprecated and will be removed in a future version.
Instructions for updating:
Use Variable.read_value. Variables in 2.X are initialized automatically both in eager and graph (inside tf.defun) contexts.

**4**

**4**

**4**

Process finished with exit code 0

What was suppose to happen was this:

*4*

*8*

*16*

Why is this happening and how to I fix it?
Thank you in advance

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You variable `my_var` is not updated when you run `my_var_times_2`. You want to also update your `my_var` with the value of `my_var_times_2`.